# Styling and formatting text using HTML and CSS

Tags: python, html, css, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy a ml model in the Heroku platform. The deployment built is successful however I am facing spacing and formatting issues in the HTML. There are certain results in which gets hidden beneath the page. I used custom css styling and new to HTML and CSS. Requesting to correct the dimension of text display so that the data will be displayed within the screen.

I shared my html and css codes

Heroku page: https://sentiment-product-reco-engine.herokuapp.com/

[![

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
.btn { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; padding: 4px 10px 4px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #333333; text-align: center;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); vertical-align: middle; background-color: #f5f5f5; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#e6e6e6, GradientType=0); border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6; border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); border: 1px solid #e6e6e6; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); cursor: pointer; *margin-left: .3em; }
.btn:hover, .btn:active, .btn.active, .btn.disabled, .btn[disabled] { background-color: #e6e6e6; }
.btn-large { padding: 9px 14px; font-size: 15px; line-height: normal; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
.btn:hover { color: #333333; text-decoration: none; background-color: #e6e6e6; background-position: 0 -15px; -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear; transition: background-position 0.1s linear; }
.btn-primary, .btn-primary:hover { text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); color: #ffffff; }
.btn-primary.active { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); }
.btn-primary { background-color: #4a77d4; background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#6eb6de), to(#4a77d4)); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-image: linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4); background-repeat: repeat-x; filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#6eb6de, endColorstr=#4a77d4, GradientType=0);  border: 1px solid #3762bc; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); }
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.active, .btn-primary.disabled, .btn-primary[disabled] { filter: none; background-color: #4a77d4; }
.btn-block { width: 100%; display:block; }

* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -ms-box-sizing:border-box; -o-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing:border-box; }

html { width: 100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; }

body { 
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background: #092756;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:1.2px;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%),-moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%, rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -o-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(0% 100%, ellipse cover, rgba(104,128,138,.4) 10%,rgba(138,114,76,0) 40%), linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(57,173,219,.25) 0%,rgba(42,60,87,.4) 100%), linear-gradient(135deg,  #670d10 0%,#092756 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );

}
.login { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -150px 0 0 -150px;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

.login h1 { color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); letter-spacing:1px; text-align:center; }

input { 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -o-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    -ms-transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
    transition: box-shadow .5s ease;
}
input:focus { box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100,100,100,0.4), 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.2); }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<!--From https://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/EGdtg-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ML API</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  
</head>

<body>
 <div class="login">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Sentiment Based Product Recommendation System</h1>

    <form align="center" action="/predict" method="post">
        
        <p style="font-size:18px;">Enter the username: </p> 
        <input type="text" style="text-align:center" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <button align="center" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Submit</button>
    </form>

   <br>
   <br>
     {{ prediction_text }}

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxbdn.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxbdn.png)

My Sample Data from the webpage : [image]

Answer (score 0):

I've changed some basic stuff for you in the styling and removed some styling from the HTML...still needs some work.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

*,*::before,*::after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 10px 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  -moz-background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  -ms-background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  -webkit-background-image: gradient(
    linear,
    0 0,
    0 100%,
    from(#ffffff),
    to(#e6e6e6)
  );
  -webkit-background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  -o-background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffff, endColorstr=#e6e6e6, GradientType=0);
  border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
    0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
    0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
    0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  *margin-left: 0.3em;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
.btn.active,
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled] {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
.btn-large {
  padding: 9px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: #333333;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-position: 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -ms-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
  transition: background-position 0.1s linear;
}
.btn-primary,
.btn-primary:hover {
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-primary.active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #4a77d4;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    0 0,
    0 100%,
    from(#6eb6de),
    to(#4a77d4)
  );
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #6eb6de, #4a77d4);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#6eb6de, endColorstr=#4a77d4, GradientType=0);
  border: 1px solid #3762bc;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2),
    0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary[disabled] {
  filter: none;
  background-color: #4a77d4;
}
.btn-block {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background: #092756;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(
      0% 100%,
      ellipse cover,
      rgba(104, 128, 138, 0.4) 10%,
      rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%
    ),
    -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(57, 173, 219, 0.25) 0%, rgba(42, 60, 87, 0.4)
          100%),
    -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(
      0% 100%,
      ellipse cover,
      rgba(104, 128, 138, 0.4) 10%,
      rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%
    ),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(57, 173, 219, 0.25) 0%, rgba(
            42,
            60,
            87,
            0.4
          )
          100%),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(
      0% 100%,
      ellipse cover,
      rgba(104, 128, 138, 0.4) 10%,
      rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%
    ),
    -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(57, 173, 219, 0.25) 0%, rgba(42, 60, 87, 0.4)
          100%),
    -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(
      0% 100%,
      ellipse cover,
      rgba(104, 128, 138, 0.4) 10%,
      rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%
    ),
    -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(57, 173, 219, 0.25) 0%, rgba(42, 60, 87, 0.4)
          100%),
    -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(
      0% 100%,
      ellipse cover,
      rgba(104, 128, 138, 0.4) 10%,
      rgba(138, 114, 76, 0) 40%
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      rgba(57, 173, 219, 0.25) 0%,
      rgba(42, 60, 87, 0.4) 100%
    ),
    linear-gradient(135deg, #670d10 0%, #092756 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3E1D6D', endColorstr='#092756',GradientType=1 );
}
.login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
  width: min(40%,400px);
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  text-align: center;
}

.login h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-align:center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.2),
    0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s ease;
}
input:focus {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 45px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.4),
    0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<!--From https://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/EGdtg-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ML API</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Sentiment Based Product Recommendation System</h1>

    <form align="center" action="/predict" method="post">

      <label for="Username">Enter the username: </label>
      <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
      <br>
      <br>
      <button align="center" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>
    {{ prediction_text }}

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```